# can't open file, no such file or directory

Tags: python, django-models, pip

when i run the code "python manage.py runserver" in my vs code terrminal, it says "can't open file" or "no such file or directory". even though the files were saved correctly. i don't know what to do.

I tried installing the python dependencies, but even after that it still did not work. it is still giving th same responses. i also tried installing the pipdetree but it still did not correct anything.
I'm a beginner. and this project is in python django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terminal write pwd and see where are you.
remember that you must be in the same directory where you run your command

if you are not in the project directory use cd command to move in the right place